# Setting new frame of imageView to frame of storyboard object

Tags: ios, swift, frame, uiviewanimation

When my app launches I have a custom splash screen that just has the logo and is designed to animate the logo so that it lines up with the frame of the logo on the login screen. So in `viewDidLoad()` I get the frame of the storyboard object, and try setting that frame as the new frame of my custom view during the animation. I'm running into a weird problem though where the custom view moves to a new location, but the view is not the size or location as expected.

Here's how I set the new frame:

```
print("Existing frame: \(self.frame)")
print("New frame: \(self.frameToExpandTo!)")
self.frame = self.frameToExpandTo!
self.frame.size = self.frameToExpandTo!.size
self.center = self.newCenter!
self.layoutIfNeeded()
print("Frame after update: \(self.frame)")
```

When the print statements are executed, I have the correct old frame and new frame of the custom view, but it's still not going where expected.

[image: Console output]

And here is what the custom view looks like after animation:[image: The smaller view to the top left is the custom view that is supposed to be in the same place as the large logo in the center, but as you can see it's in the wrong place and has the wrong size.]

What am I doing wrong? Just starting to get into animations more so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but hopefully someone can point it out to me.

Comment: What is self.frameToExpandTo ? How you retrieve it?

Comment: In my `viewDidLoad` where I create my custom `subView`, I set `splashIcon.frameToExpandTo = self.logoView.frame` where `logoView` is an `IBOutlet` connected to the logo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much talk and thanks to @DisableR, I found my solution. It included getting the new frame like this in my custom function: `splashIcon!.frameToExpandTo = splashIcon!.superview!.convertRect(self.logoView.bounds, fromView: self.logoView)`

And further, instead of calling this custom function in `viewDidLoad`, I called it in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` which gives me the correct frames for the animation that I'm trying to accomplish.

I realize now that the frame being printed out in my original question was the frame set in storyboard, not the one for where the logo actually was on the view, so calling this in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` gives me the correct frame at the right time, without any stutter by showing the underlying view first like it did if my custom function was called in `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
splashIcon.frameToExpandTo = self.logoView.window!.convertRect(self.logoView.bounds, fromView:self.logoView)
```

And then to your code snippet in the question:

```
self.frame = self.window!.convertRect(self.frameToExpandTo!, toView:self)
```

But this will require to be performed in `viewDidAppear`, because on `viewDidLoad` you  have no window yet.

If your viewController's view is a supersede view to both self.logoView and to splashIcon, then conversion will work from viewDidLoad, but you will need to do it with the view of your view controller instead of the window. E.g.

```
splashIcon.frameToExpandTo = self.splashIcon.superview!.convertRect(self.logoView.bounds, fromView:self.logoView)
```

and

```
self.frame = self.frameToExpandTo!
```

Comment: Okay progress! This did work but because it's in `viewDidAppear` the underlying view appears first and this makes the UI look like it's stuttering. Any recommendation?

Comment: The problem is in different coordinate systems. Unfortunately, until your splashIcon is on a window (thus, viewDidAppear has been called), there is no legal way to convert coordinates from one view hierarchy to another. Only hardcoding will do the job in this case.

Comment: Well I can't hardcode because it has to work on all screen sizes. But shouldn't the frame already be set in `viewDidLoad`? It's an implicitly unwrapped optional and you should have access to the frame from there.

Comment: If I try your edit the custom view goes back to the location is was going in my original question.

Comment: are self.logoView and splashIcon available in viewDidLoad together?

Comment: The logo view is an `IBOutlet` on the `viewController` and the `splashIcon` is created in code in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Updated answer :)  self.splashIcon.superview!.convertRect

Comment: Updated answer still gives same behavior as original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93924/discussion-between-pbush25-and-disabler).